# get facebook feed based on 'updated_time'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get all last comments, which was made on my page. I know that each post have field called `updated_time` which updates each time when someone make a comment to the post. So what I really need is to get all posts, with `updated_time` after some moment.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `since` parameter in your request:

```
/{page_id}/feed?fields=id,message,updated_time,comments&since={unix_timestamp}
```

Replace `{page_id}` with the actual Page_ID, and `{unix_timestamp}` with the actual desired timestamp for the last changes.

Comment: This is a `WRONG` answer. This request return data orderd buy post creation time, but not for updated_time. So if you post a comment to some data, which was published long time ago, this request do not allow you to get this info.

Comment: Funny, I checked this with an example post with a comment later than the post, and it worked

Comment: than it's simply mean that you put incorrect timestamp (probably miss UTC difference). Try it with old posts, who is day or weeks and you will find that it's not work